# cuDNN installed but could not initializing

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to train SegNet on my computer. I have GTX860M graphic card. nvidia-driver-440, cuda 10.1 and cuDNN7 already installed but error messages is saying that couldn't create cudnn handle. cuDNN is working without any problem for my other models. I tried to decrease batch size but it didn't help. How can I fix this problem?

Error

```
Epoch 1/10
2020-06-18 18:59:04.172516: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2020-06-18 18:59:04.664514: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:329] Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED
2020-06-18 18:59:04.664608: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:337] Possibly insufficient driver version: 440.82.0
2020-06-18 18:59:04.666215: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:329] Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED
2020-06-18 18:59:04.666252: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:337] Possibly insufficient driver version: 440.82.0
```

nvcc --version

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Jul_28_19:07:16_PDT_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.243
```

cat /usr/local/cuda/include/cudnn.h | grep CUDNN_MAJOR -A 2

```
#define CUDNN_MAJOR 7
#define CUDNN_MINOR 6
#define CUDNN_PATCHLEVEL 5
--
#define CUDNN_VERSION (CUDNN_MAJOR * 1000 + CUDNN_MINOR * 100 + CUDNN_PATCHLEVEL)

#include "driver_types.h"
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. It was memory allocation problem.

```
from keras.backend.tensorflow_backend import set_session
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
assert len(physical_devices) > 0, "Not enough GPU hardware devices available"
config = tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
sess = tf.Session(config=config)
set_session(sess)
```

https://kobkrit.com/using-allow-growth-memory-option-in-tensorflow-and-keras-dc8c8081bc96